# Express.js dynamic routes

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm trying to make tiny CMS using Node.js and Express.js, I wonder what is the best way to routes the module dynamically. I red documents some I could understand, and some I couldn't understand. What is a proper way to do it?

If a user(usually site administrator) make a static pages, forums, and some modules named all different :

- staticPage
- QnAforum
- andAnythingUserNamed

I think two way to routes this page,

**First** : I think it is sane way, and URL is clean, but possible to decrease page loading speed.

```
app.get(/:module, function(req, res, next){
    ...

    // if req.params.modules == (login || logout ...)
    // handle it 
    // else if 
    // module.find()... and render... 

});
```

**Second** : If I separate module user made, I think the URL is more complicated, but it is faster site loading than above way.

```
app.get(/forum/:id, function(req, res, next){
    ...
    // forum.find({forum_id: req.params.id})... 

});

app.get(/staticPage/:id, function(req, res, next){
    ...
    // staticPage.find({staticPage_id: req.params.id})... 
});
```

Is there a proper way to using cleaner URL, and fast loading both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refine your first approach by defining all the 'static' routes first, and then following with your dynamic router, like this:

```
app.get('/login', function (req, res) { /* ... */ });

app.get('/logout', function (req, res) { /* ... */ });

app.get('/:dynamicRoute', function (req, res) { 
  res.send(res.params.dynamicRoute);
});
```

Comment: if i am using the dynamic routing then my css file does not render !!!

Answer (score 2):

First define all the static routes:

```
app.get(/forum/:id, function(req, res, next){
    ...
    // forum.find({forum_id: req.params.id})... 

});
```

Now, to create static pages for a CMS, just create a custom middleware under the path `/` and search the request path in the database to check if a page exists.

```
// page storage
// could be MySQL, MongoDb or anything else you are using
var pages = require(......);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // find page in the database using the request path
    pages.findPage(req.path, funcion(err, page) {
        // error occured, so we call express error handler
        if (err) return next(err);

        // no page exists, so call the next middleware
        if (!page) return next();

        // page found
        // so render the page and return response
        // return res.status(200).render(...........);
    });
});
```